# SARS-CoV-2 virus floating in the air in *aerosols* for up to 3 hours

Tags: environmental-chemistry

I have a question related to SARS-CoV-2 virus spreaded in the air.

This [Straits Time article](https://www.straitstimes.com/world/united-states/coronavirus-covid-19-bug-can-persist-in-air-for-hours-and-on-surfaces-for-days) from March 18 describes a new study:

> The tests show that when the virus is carried by the droplets released when someone coughs or sneezes, it remains viable, or able to still infect people, in aerosols for at least three hours.

Examples of aerosol are fog, dust, particulate air pollutants (e.g. pollen), smoke, etc.

That being said, is essentially saying that the SARS-CoV-2 virus is *all over* in the air, right?

I am saying that SARS-CoV-2 virus can be *everywhere* in the world. Why? Because, for example, dust is everywhere in the air and air is not static, i.e. "it flies" from one site to another and hence it can move to a place where no infected people have been at.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sneezing may be considered as one early vector of transmission.  According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneeze, the droplets ejected by a sneeze are in the micrometer range, travel with 4.5 m/s for 0.6 m.  The two later values are _much less_ than I thought, esp. with the current rule to keep at least 1.5 m distance to the next when going for the groceries.  With a known diameter and density of a virus _vs._ the density of air, it would become a question for fluid mechanics / phys.se to derive how much time is required for a virus to fall to the ground without lateral wind, etc.

Comment: This question should be closed due to the medical exclusion. We are chemists not qualified medical professionals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because to derive how long a micrometer-small particle of density $\varrho_A$ may stay afloat in air of density $\varrho_B$ seems more suitable for sibling site phys.se.

Comment: @Buttonwood ok.

Comment: @Buttonwood sir I just asked it on physics and I have just notice that someone has posted an answer here :O

Comment: @America - Thinking you can make this a purely "physical chemistry" problem while mentioning the "SARS-CoV-2 virus" in both the question's title and body is ludicrous. Even trying to ask about some hypothetical virus would do little to hide the intent in the current panic.  Because we are not qualified medical professionals we need to stay out of such "hypothetical" discussions to avoid spreading misinformation.

Comment: @MaxW The reason on why I decided to name the virus as "SARS-CoV-2 virus" it's because on another SE site  I was told to name the virus with the proper name. In general I had wrote Covid-19.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### You are not understanding it correctly

There is a significant difference between an aerosol, dust and droplets. Furthermore the intermixing of air is not as you claim it is, it is in fact, quite static. If air just went everywhere immediately there would not be clouds, temperature differences, or indeed any weather effects at all.

A question you could ask yourself is: With my current understanding, covid-19 should be everywhere. There should not exist differences between cities and rural areas, or between countries. But there is.

Listen to the advice of health services and the government. They know their shit.

Comment: -1 You can answer a question without being patronising to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not a physician, but afaiu air is not static, by just looking at trees and how their leaves are moving I can tell that there's air movement. And hence spreading virus from one place to another.

Comment: -1 We need to stay out of such "hypothetical" discussions to avoid spreading misinformation.This is a medical question which we are not qualified to answer.